# JPA 2.0 CriteriaBuilder : SELECT FROM … IN

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria

I want to create the following SQL query using JPA 2.0 CriteriaBuilder :

```
SELECT * FROM PROFIL WHERE PROFILID IN (SELECT PROFILID FROM ROLEPROFIL WHERE ROLEID = roleId)
```

Here are my classes :

**Profil :**

```
public class Profil extends AbstractDomain<Long> {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idgen_x")
    @UiInfo(name = "Identifiant")
    private Long profilId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @UiInfo(name = "Libellé")
    private String lib;

}
```

**Role :**

```
public class Role extends AbstractDomain<Long> {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idgen_x")
    @UiInfo(name = "Identifiant")
    private Long roleId;
}
```

**RoleProfil :**

```
public class RoleProfil extends AbstractDomain<Long> {
    @Id
    @Column
    @UiInfo(name = "Identifiant")
    private Long roleProfilId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @UiInfo(name = "Profil")
    private Profil profilId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @UiInfo(name = "Rôle")
    private Role roleId;

}
```

What I want to do is to create a function that will get `Profils` by a `Role` ID, using JPA.

This is what I started, but I'm new to JPA and I couldn't figure out how to do it :

```
public List<Profil> findProfilsByRoleId(Long roleId) {
        final CriteriaBuilder builder = getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<Profil> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Profil.class);
        final Root<Profil> from = criteriaQuery.from(Profil.class);

        //TODO

        TypedQuery<Profil> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        return query.getResultList();

    }
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  PF.* 
FROM PROFIL AS PF
INNER JOIN ROLEPROFIL AS RPF
ON RPF.PROFILID = PF.PROFILID 
WHERE RPF.ROLEID = {roleId}
```

Might be a more easy to implement query. I think the code in java could be something like this (I have not tested just proposed solution):

```
public List<Profil> findProfilsByRoleId(Long roleId) {
    final CriteriaBuilder builder = getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<Profil> query = builder.createQuery(Profil.class);
    final Root<RoleProfil> from = query.from(RoleProfil.class);

    query.select(from.get(RoleProfil_.profilId));
    query.where(builder.equal(from.get(RoleProfil_.roleId).get(Role_.roleId), roleId));

    final TypedQuery<Profil> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(query);
    return typedQuery.getResultList();

}
```

Comment: That sql query will return both columns in `PROFIL` and `ROLEPROFIL`

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that you used `Profil_.RoleProfil` I don't think this will work since I've no `RoleProfil` in `Profil`, and you used `query.where` when `query` is not defined.

Comment: Updated again. Not sure if it runs though, i haven't used the criteria API thoroughly.

Comment: emm, I don't know if this `RoleProfil_.Profil` should work, but I get an error saying that `Profil cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: Updated. Feel free to do your own experiments too.

Comment: yeah sorry, well the solution was as following :
- The Root should be `RoleProfil` and not `Profil`.
- There will be no `Join in` this case since `RoleProfil` is already referring `Profil`.
- There should be a select to select only the `Profil` from the result.
- and for the `equal` it has to be between the param and the the id from `Role_` and not the `RoleProfil_.roleId` which is an object